# MySQL - Error on adding foreign keys

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys

I used the following query to add a foreign key to my Table:

```
$query = "ALTER TABLE reserved ADD CONSTRAINT fk_test FOREIGN KEY (personel_num) REFERENCES members (personel_num) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE;";
if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) {
    return true;
} else {
    echo $conn->error;
}
```

But I got the following Error:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1`

`personel_num` in table `members` is a Primary Key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
    $query = "ALTER TABLE reserved ADD CONSTRAINT fk_test FOREIGN KEY (personel_num)
 REFERENCES members members (personel_num) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION;";
```

Answer (score 1):

The `;` is not part of the SQL syntax, it's just a terminator some tools use to signify where the SQL statement ended. 
Since you're sending the SQL statement to the database programatically, you don't need it.

Additionally, you should specify `NO ACTION` when updating:

```
$query = "ALTER TABLE reserved ADD CONSTRAINT fk_test " .
         "FOREIGN KEY (personel_num) REFERENCES members (personel_num) " .
         "ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION";
```